# Does XMonad has screen sleep?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, x11, xmonad, tiling-wm

My story is a bit long. I have a Linux Mint Tricia. It comes with Cinnamon, after a while, I started using XFCE and removed Cinnamon. After a while, I installed GNOME and removed XFCE and now I installed XMonad ( but not removed GNOME ). I am with a problem: My screen comes black after a while. I do not want this! Is that a XMonad thing or a X11 thing? Or a GNOME thing that is interfering on my XMonad?

I have XMonad + XMobar + nitrogen + compton.

My XMonad config:

```haskell
--
-- xmonad example config file.
--
-- A template showing all available configuration hooks,
-- and how to override the defaults in your own xmonad.hs conf file.
--
-- Normally, you'd only override those defaults you care about.
--

import XMonad
import Data.Monoid
import System.Exit
import XMonad.Util.Run
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Layout.Grid
import XMonad.Actions.Volume -- To change and get the volume
import XMonad.Util.Dzen      -- To show the volume
import XMonad.Layout.Spacing
import XMonad.Layout.ResizableTile
import XMonad.Layout.Tabbed
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
-- import XMonad.Layout.TwoPane
import XMonad.Layout.BinarySpacePartition

import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import qualified Data.Map        as M

-- The preferred terminal program, which is used in a binding below and by
-- certain contrib modules.
--
myTerminal      = "gnome-terminal"

-- Whether focus follows the mouse pointer.
myFocusFollowsMouse :: Bool
myFocusFollowsMouse = False

-- Whether clicking on a window to focus also passes the click to the window
myClickJustFocuses :: Bool
myClickJustFocuses = False


myBorderWidth        = 1

myModMask            = mod4Mask

myWorkspaces         = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

myNormalBorderColor  = "#282a36"
myFocusedBorderColor = "#ff5555"


alert = dzenConfig centered . show . round
centered = 
        onCurr (center 200 100)
    >=> addArgs ["-fg", "#f8f8f2"]
    >=> addArgs ["-bg", "#282a36"]

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Key bindings. Add, modify or remove key bindings here.
--
myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $

    -- launch a terminal
    [ ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_Return), spawn $ XMonad.terminal conf)

    -- volume
    , ((modm,               xK_F6), lowerVolume 4 >>= alert)
    , ((modm,               xK_F7), raiseVolume 4 >>= alert)
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_F6), lowerVolume 1 >>= alert)
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_F7), raiseVolume 1 >>= alert)

    -- launch dmenu
    , ((modm,               xK_p     ), spawn "dmenu_run -l 20")

    -- launch gmrun
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_p     ), spawn "gmrun")

    -- Take a screenshot
    , ((0                 , xK_Print ), spawn "xfce4-screenshooter")

    -- close focused window
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_c     ), kill)

     -- Rotate through the available layout algorithms
    , ((modm,               xK_space ), sendMessage NextLayout)

    --  Reset the layouts on the current workspace to default
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_space ), setLayout $ XMonad.layoutHook conf)

    -- Resize viewed windows to the correct size
    , ((modm,               xK_n     ), refresh)

    -- Move focus to the next window
    , ((modm,               xK_Tab   ), windows W.focusDown)

    -- Move focus to the next window
    , ((modm,               xK_j     ), windows W.focusDown)

    -- Move focus to the previous window
    , ((modm,               xK_k     ), windows W.focusUp  )

    -- Move focus to the master window
    , ((modm,               xK_m     ), windows W.focusMaster  )

    -- Swap the focused window and the master window
    , ((modm,               xK_Return), windows W.swapMaster)

    -- Swap the focused window with the next window
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_j     ), windows W.swapDown  )

    -- Swap the focused window with the previous window
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_k     ), windows W.swapUp    )

    -- Shrink the master area
    , ((modm,               xK_h     ), sendMessage Shrink)

    -- Expand the master area
    , ((modm,               xK_l     ), sendMessage Expand)

    -- Shink the non master area
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_h     ), sendMessage MirrorShrink)

    -- Expand the non master area
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_l     ), sendMessage MirrorExpand)

    -- Push window back into tiling
    , ((modm,               xK_t     ), withFocused $ windows . W.sink)

    -- Increment the number of windows in the master area
    , ((modm              , xK_comma ), sendMessage (IncMasterN 1))

    -- Deincrement the number of windows in the master area
    , ((modm              , xK_period), sendMessage (IncMasterN (-1)))

    -- Toggle the status bar gap
    -- Use this binding with avoidStruts from Hooks.ManageDocks.
    -- See also the statusBar function from Hooks.DynamicLog.
    --
    -- , ((modm              , xK_b     ), sendMessage ToggleStruts)

    -- Quit xmonad
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_q     ), io (exitWith ExitSuccess))

    -- Restart xmonad
    , ((modm              , xK_q     ), spawn "killall xmobar; xmonad --recompile; xmonad --restart")

    -- Run xmessage with a summary of the default keybindings (useful for beginners)
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_slash ), spawn ("echo \"" ++ help ++ "\" | xmessage -file -"))
    ]
    ++

    --
    -- mod-[1..9], Switch to workspace N
    -- mod-shift-[1..9], Move client to workspace N
    --
    [((m .|. modm, k), windows $ f i)
        | (i, k) <- zip (XMonad.workspaces conf) [xK_1 .. xK_9]
        , (f, m) <- [(W.greedyView, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]
    ++

    --
    -- mod-{w,e,r}, Switch to physical/Xinerama screens 1, 2, or 3
    -- mod-shift-{w,e,r}, Move client to screen 1, 2, or 3
    --
    [((m .|. modm, key), screenWorkspace sc >>= flip whenJust (windows . f))
        | (key, sc) <- zip [xK_w, xK_e, xK_r] [0..]
        , (f, m) <- [(W.view, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]


------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Mouse bindings: default actions bound to mouse events
--
myMouseBindings (XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $

    -- mod-button1, Set the window to floating mode and move by dragging
    [ ((modm, button1), (\w -> focus w >> mouseMoveWindow w
                                       >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button2, Raise the window to the top of the stack
    , ((modm, button2), (\w -> focus w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button3, Set the window to floating mode and resize by dragging
    , ((modm, button3), (\w -> focus w >> mouseResizeWindow w
                                       >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- you may also bind events to the mouse scroll wheel (button4 and button5)
    ]

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Layouts:

-- You can specify and transform your layouts by modifying these values.
-- If you change layout bindings be sure to use 'mod-shift-space' after
-- restarting (with 'mod-q') to reset your layout state to the new
-- defaults, as xmonad preserves your old layout settings by default.
--
-- The available layouts.  Note that each layout is separated by |||,
-- which denotes layout choice.


-- Tabbed style config
myTabConfig = def { activeColor = "#303030"
                  , inactiveColor = "#000000"
                  , urgentColor = "#fdf6e3"
                  , activeBorderColor = "#303030"
                  , inactiveBorderColor = "#000000"
                  , urgentBorderColor = "#fdf6e3"
                  , activeTextColor = "#f8f8f8"
                  , inactiveTextColor = "#a0a0a0"
                  , urgentTextColor = "#1ABC9C"
                  , fontName = "xft:FiraCode:size=10:antialias=true"
                  }


myLayout = (tiled ||| bsp ||| tabs ||| fullscreen)
  where
     -- default tiling algorithm partitions the screen into two panes with more adjustment
     tiled       = avoidStruts $ spacing 5 $ (ResizableTall nmaster delta ratio [])
     mirrortiled = avoidStruts $ spacing 5 $ Mirror $ (ResizableTall nmaster delta ratio [])

     -- Real fullscreen
     fullscreen  = noBorders $ Full

     -- Tabbed windows
     tabs        = avoidStruts $ noBorders $ tabbed shrinkText myTabConfig

     -- Selected window divides into two
     bsp         = avoidStruts $ spacing 5 $ emptyBSP

     -- The default number of windows in the master pane
     nmaster     = 1

     -- Default proportion of screen occupied by master pane
     ratio       = 1/2

     -- Percent of screen to increment by when resizing panes
     delta       = 3/100

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Window rules:

-- Execute arbitrary actions and WindowSet manipulations when managing
-- a new window. You can use this to, for example, always float a
-- particular program, or have a client always appear on a particular
-- workspace.
--
-- To find the property name associated with a program, use
-- > xprop | grep WM_CLASS
-- and click on the client you're interested in.
--
-- To match on the WM_NAME, you can use 'title' in the same way that
-- 'className' and 'resource' are used below.
--
myManageHook = composeAll
    [ className =? "MPlayer"        --> doFloat
    , className =? "Gimp"           --> doFloat
    , resource  =? "desktop_window" --> doIgnore
    , resource  =? "kdesktop"       --> doIgnore ]

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Event handling

-- * EwmhDesktops users should change this to ewmhDesktopsEventHook
--
-- Defines a custom handler function for X Events. The function should
-- return (All True) if the default handler is to be run afterwards. To
-- combine event hooks use mappend or mconcat from Data.Monoid.
--
myEventHook = mempty

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Status bars and logging

-- Perform an arbitrary action on each internal state change or X event.
-- See the 'XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog' extension for examples.
--
--myLogHook = dynamicLogWithPP $
--          xmobarPP {
--                   ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc
--                   }

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Startup hook

-- Perform an arbitrary action each time xmonad starts or is restarted
-- with mod-q.  Used by, e.g., XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace to initialize
-- per-workspace layout choices.
--
-- By default, do nothing.
myStartupHook = return ()
    

myPP = def { ppCurrent = xmobarColor "#1ABC9C" "" . wrap "[" "]"
           , ppTitle = xmobarColor "#1ABC9C" "" . shorten 60
           , ppVisible = wrap "(" ")"
           , ppUrgent  = xmobarColor "red" "yellow"
           }


main = do
    h <- spawnPipe "xmobar -x 0 /home/arthur/.config/xmobar/xmobarrc"
    xmonad $ docks def {
      -- simple stuff
        terminal           = myTerminal,
        focusFollowsMouse  = myFocusFollowsMouse,
        clickJustFocuses   = myClickJustFocuses,
        borderWidth        = myBorderWidth,
        modMask            = myModMask,
        workspaces         = myWorkspaces,
        normalBorderColor  = myNormalBorderColor,
        focusedBorderColor = myFocusedBorderColor,

      -- key bindings
        keys               = myKeys,
        mouseBindings      = myMouseBindings,

      -- hooks, layouts
        layoutHook         = myLayout,
        manageHook         = myManageHook,
        handleEventHook    = myEventHook,
        logHook            = dynamicLogWithPP $ myPP {
                                                     ppOutput = hPutStrLn h
                                                     },
        startupHook        = myStartupHook
    }
    

-- | Finally, a copy of the default bindings in simple textual tabular format.
help :: String
help = unlines ["The default modifier key is 'alt'. Default keybindings:",
    "",
    "-- launching and killing programs",
    "mod-Shift-Enter  Launch xterminal",
    "mod-p            Launch dmenu",
    "mod-Shift-p      Launch gmrun",
    "mod-Shift-c      Close/kill the focused window",
    "mod-Space        Rotate through the available layout algorithms",
    "mod-Shift-Space  Reset the layouts on the current workSpace to default",
    "mod-n            Resize/refresh viewed windows to the correct size",
    "",
    "-- move focus up or down the window stack",
    "mod-Tab        Move focus to the next window",
    "mod-Shift-Tab  Move focus to the previous window",
    "mod-j          Move focus to the next window",
    "mod-k          Move focus to the previous window",
    "mod-m          Move focus to the master window",
    "",
    "-- modifying the window order",
    "mod-Return   Swap the focused window and the master window",
    "mod-Shift-j  Swap the focused window with the next window",
    "mod-Shift-k  Swap the focused window with the previous window",
    "",
    "-- resizing the master/slave ratio",
    "mod-h  Shrink the master area",
    "mod-l  Expand the master area",
    "",
    "-- floating layer support",
    "mod-t  Push window back into tiling; unfloat and re-tile it",
    "",
    "-- increase or decrease number of windows in the master area",
    "mod-comma  (mod-,)   Increment the number of windows in the master area",
    "mod-period (mod-.)   Deincrement the number of windows in the master area",
    "",
    "-- quit, or restart",
    "mod-Shift-q  Quit xmonad",
    "mod-q        Restart xmonad",
    "mod-[1..9]   Switch to workSpace N",
    "",
    "-- Workspaces & screens",
    "mod-Shift-[1..9]   Move client to workspace N",
    "mod-{w,e,r}        Switch to physical/Xinerama screens 1, 2, or 3",
    "mod-Shift-{w,e,r}  Move client to screen 1, 2, or 3",
    "",
    "-- Mouse bindings: default actions bound to mouse events",
    "mod-button1  Set the window to floating mode and move by dragging",
    "mod-button2  Raise the window to the top of the stack",
    "mod-button3  Set the window to floating mode and resize by dragging",
    "",
    "-- Arthur things",
    "mod-Shift-s  Cmatrix screen saver"]
```

And my XMobar config:

```haskell
Config { font = "xft:FiraCode:pixelsize=12:antialias=true:hinting=true"
       , additionalFonts = []
       , border = NoBorder
       , borderColor = "#c8c8c8"
       , bgColor = "#0f0f0f"
       , fgColor = "#ededed"
       , alpha = 0
       , position = Top
       , textOffset = -1
       , iconOffset = -1
       , lowerOnStart = True
       , pickBroadest = False
       , persistent = False
       , hideOnStart = False
       , iconRoot = "."
       , allDesktops = True
       , overrideRedirect = True
       , commands = [ Run Weather "EGPF" [ "-t"         , "<station>: <tempC>C"
                                         , "-L"         , "18"
                                         , "-H"         , "25"
                                         , "--normal"   , "green"
                                         , "--high"     , "red"
                                         , "--low"      , "lightblue"
                                         ] 36000

                    , Run Network "eth0" [ "-L"         , "0"
                                         , "-H"         , "32"
                                         , "--normal"   , "green"
                                         , "--high"     , "red"
                                         ] 10

                    , Run Network "eth1" [ "-L"         , "0"
                                         , "-H"         , "32"
                                         , "--normal"   , "green"
                                         , "--high"     , "red"
                                         ] 10

                    , Run MultiCpu       [ "--template" , "Cpu: <total0>% <total1>% <total2>% <total3>%"
                                         , "--Low"      , "50"         -- units: %
                                         , "--High"     , "85"         -- units: %
                                         , "--low"      , "green"
                                         , "--normal"   , "yellow"
                                         , "--high"     , "red"
                                         ] 10

                    , Run CoreTemp       [ "--template" , "Temp: <core0>°C <core1>°C <core2>°C"
                                         , "--Low"      , "70"
                                         , "--High"     , "80"
                                         , "--low"      , "green"
                                         , "--normal"   , "yellow"
                                         , "--high"     , "red"
                                         ] 10

                    , Run Memory         [ "--template" , "Mem: <usedratio>%"
                                         , "--Low"      , "20"
                                         , "--High"     , "80"
                                         , "--low"      , "green"
                                         , "--normal"   , "yellow"
                                         , "--high"     , "red"
                                         ] 10

                    , Run Swap           [
                                         ] 10

                    , Run Com "uname"    [ "-s"
                                         , "-r"
                                         ] "" 36000

                    , Run Date "%a %b %_d %Y %H:%M:%S" "date" 10

                    , Run StdinReader

                    --, Run Com "bash" [ "-c" , "echo $(protonvpn s | grep Server | xargs -n 1 echo | tail -n 1 && protonvpn s | grep IP | xargs -n 1 echo | tail -n 1) | xargs echo"
                    --                 ] "myip" 50
                    ]
       , sepChar = "%"
       , alignSep = "}{"
       , template = "%StdinReader%    %memory%  %multicpu%  %coretemp%}\
                    \{%date%"
       }
```

And my XSession

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# This script runs before tha xmonad initialization
# Here there are some configurations and opens some programs

# CapsLock key comes a alternative Super key
setxkbmap -option "caps:super" &

# Configures mouse pointer to appear correctly
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr &

# Draws the wallpaper
nitrogen --restore &

# Enables transparency
compton &

# Starts XMonad
xmonad
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No, XMonad does not have any functionality to blank/sleep your screen

The screen sleep/blank settings are completely managed by X. Depending on your operating system, certain defaults will be set for screen blanking after N minutes of inactivity. Debian-based systems will blank the screen after 10 minutes.

The reason you're not noticing this with desktop environments other than XMonad, is that they *do* implement their own utilities for setting screen timeouts.

The way to set your X settings is with the command `xset`. To completely disable screen saving/blanking/disabling you will need to issue the following commands:

```
$ xset s off
$ xset s 0 0
$ xset -dpms
```

To execute these on every startup, place them in the file named `~/.xsessionrc` or in the file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90custom_nosleep` to disable screen blanking system-wide.

Comment: Thank you so much.